# Increasing fps when grabbing from screen

Tags: python, compiler-construction, python-imaging-library, frame-rate, screen-grab

i want to record scenes from my screen, only keeping those that contain a certain pixelcolor. 
I have already written a screengrabber using python for this:

```
import PIL.ImageGrab 

def get_pixel_colour(i_x, i_y):
    return PIL.ImageGrab.grab().load()[i_x, i_y]   

print get_pixel_colour(0, 1)

i= 0 
while (True):
     i=i+1
     x = PIL.ImageGrab.grab()
     print i
     x.save("tm\screengrab"+ str(i) +".bmp")
```

The thing is my frames per second are not enough to produce a video. I would at least need 25 fps for that, i think. How can i improve the performance of my screengrabber so that it works? I want to keep python as production language, if possible, as i am not as adept in C++.

Is there something like a compiler for python perhaps?

Comment: The code in the question has some line break and indentation problems. Please edit the question to fix those.

Comment: Think I fixed it - @tarrasch, can you check this is what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

How big is your screen?

If you want to screen grab a 1920x1080 screen at 25fps, and write to a bmp at 25fps you are going to need some much better hardware and probably a totally different software approach.

Comment: i get my screen at a resolution of 1024x798. i hope to fix this with an optimization rather than new hardware. I can for example write to another harddisc, other than the system itself

Comment: That's still 60Mb/s which is high for a random write to a single disk - even assuming the PIL is efficient

Comment: i changed it now to jpg. see if that helps. Can you show me how to modify my code to show me the number of writes per second?